# how to schedule a job on Oracle SQL developer to execute shell command "Java -Jar /Home/JavaFile.jar" each one minute?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle12c

I would like to create an oracle job that runs every one minute to run command `Java -jar /Home/file_name.jar"`, i am using Oracle SQL developer on windows environment to connect to Oracle DB on Linux environment.

Comment: I already created a job  on Oracle SQL developer by right click on job under schedule then create new job using wizard but i can't specify the job type and i tried all the options and all of them gave me error.

Comment: Why is this a job for the database and not a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple way as below:

1- Connect on linux server using Putty or anything.
2-run command `crontab -e`
3-edit crontab by clicking i then type java command ex: `* * * * * java -jar /root/filename.jar` and this means that this jar file will be called each one minutes

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** you need to first load this java program in oracle so that it can run on jvm installed in oracle database...
ref link [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm](http://calling%20java%20methods%20from%20oracle)

**step 2** then you need to create function or procedure to run this java program say

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloworld RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Hello.world () return java.lang.String';
```

**step 3** then you need to create job or scheduler in oracle to run this oracle function it will internally call your java method.
follow the link to create job
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12381](http://scheduler)

Comment: thank you, but you didn't provide me with new thing as i already ran command Java -jar on server it self through the shell prompt and it works, but my problem now with the Job it self how could i do a job to call jar file !?

Comment: can you please specify you exact requirement are you going call any method inside java then in have given sample code **or** do you need some diff kind of functionality.